# jQuery each() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Am I doing something wrong here? I have an array of tags, and when I do a jQuery `each()` on the array it doesn't go into the `each()` I did have an `alert` in the each but nothing happens. I have checked my error log console and there are no errors. So, what am I doing wrong?

```
var tags = new Array();
tags["video-games"] = "Video Games";
tags["sports"] = "Sports";
tags["movies"] = "Movies";
tags["board-games"] = "Board Games";
tags["news"] = "News";
tags["television"] = "Television";
tags["computers"] = "Computers";
tags["opinions"] = "Opinions";
tags["reviews"] = "Reviews";

function updateTags(){
    console.log(tags);
    $("div.tags > div > span:first-child").nextAll().remove();
    $.each(tags, function(key, val){
        $("div.tags > div").append("<span><a class='tag' href='/tags/" + key + "'>" + val + "</a></span>");

    });
}

updateTags();
```

Comment: Arrays don't work like that, use an object.

Comment: String keys are not supported javascript array

Comment: You used `Array[]` like `Object {}`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Arrays are expected to have numeric indexes.
You've created an empty array which happens to have some properties.

You should create an ordinary object instead:

```
var tags = {
    "video-games": "Video Games",
    ...
};
```

Comment: I agree. As you have a key-value pair use th eobject and use the Javascript `for(var key in obj){console.log(obj[key]);}` to get the expected results

Answer (score 0):

So in this case

```
var tags = {};
tags["video-games"] = "Video Games";
tags["sports"] = "Sports";
tags["movies"] = "Movies";
tags["board-games"] = "Board Games";
tags["news"] = "News";
tags["television"] = "Television";
tags["computers"] = "Computers";
tags["opinions"] = "Opinions";
tags["reviews"] = "Reviews";

function updateTags(){
    //console.log(tags);
    $("div.tags > div > span:first-child").nextAll().remove();
    for(var key in tags){
        $("div.tags > div").append("<span><a class='tag' href='/tags/" + key + "'>" + tags[key] + "</a></span>");
    }
}

updateTags();
```

Should work.

Comment: don't forget about Object.hasOwnProperty (In this case I don't see it making a difference), when iterating object keys it is a good thing to remember

Answer (score 0):

Your code is object and properties

```
var tags = {};
tags["video-games"] = "Video Games";
```

or

```
var tags = {
"video-games" : "Video Games";
};
```

Then

```
$.each(tags, function(key, val) {
    $("div.tags > div").append("<span><a class='tag' href='/tags/" + key + "'>" 
                                + val + "</a></span>");

});
```

Comment: in your second example you would get an invalid left hand side in assignment error because it sees the '-' as a operator and not part of the property name. Only bracket notation can be used for such names

Comment: @rlemon, Thanks for informing.. I didnt noted `-` :( I will get change it

Comment: your new example will also throw errors, you need to replace the '=' with ':' in object literal property assignments, and drop the semi-colon inside the object. `var tags = { 'video-games' : 'Video Games' };`